# Restful methods not working

Tags: java, rest, openshift

I created an openshift application. When i run it on my local server it works(the calls to the method give a response), but on the openshift server it can't find the method of my resteasy web service. I get a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). 
this is my web xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And this is my web service:

```
 @Stateless // without this i get a 405
 @Path("/issue")
 @Produces("application/json")
 @Consumes("application/json")
 public class IssueRestService {

 private static final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(IssueRestService.class);


private IssueBeanLocal issueLocalBean;


@POST
@Path("/loadProjects")
public List<Object[]> loadProjects(Map<String, Object> params){
    String table = params.get("table").toString();
    try{
        List<Object[]> response = issueLocalBean.loadDDL(table);
        return response;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("error in getting the DDL data. Error message :  " + e.getMessage());
        return null;

    }

}
```

}

The url that i use in my ajax calls is : "/{projectname}/rest/issue/loadProjects"

I'm new to all this and i don't have much experience in programming so i hope this is not a dumb question or a repost.

Comment: How are you deploying your project to OpenShift?  Are you doing a git push with a maven based project? Or are you deploying a WAR file?

Comment: A git push. The project is maven based. I find out that if i modify the link to be like this /rest/issue/loadProjects it kind of works. I have to do some more developing to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url on OpenShift will be http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/rest/issue/loadProjects, whereas on your local development environment they run with the project name like http://{localhost}:8080/{projectname}/rest/issue/loadProjects.